# Double asterstik in c. Why its showing error when I dont use it in this following program?

Tags: c, char

I am trying to figure out this program and not understanding the usage of this double asterisk. I know it means a pointer to char but never used it before.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void fun(int **p);
int main()
{
    int a[3][4] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 8, 7, 8, 9, 0};
    int *ptr;
    ptr = &a[0][0];
    fun(&ptr);
    return 0;
}

void fun(int **p)
{
    printf("%d\n", **p);
}
```

Comment: Please specify the exact error you get. In general `**` means a pointer to a pointer (i.e. add one more level of indirection over a single `*` pointer).

Comment: when I only used one asterisk, its showing me error. Sometimes it just send me some random number. Maybe address

Answer (score 1):

There are three occurrences of the double asterisk in you original problem, and it’s unclear if you’re talking about a compiler error, a runtime “segfault” error, or the program didn’t throw an error but just didn’t print the results you expected, so there’s ambiguity in your question. But one explanation should clarify all.

The type of `ptr` is an int pointer (`int*`), so the type of `&ptr` becomes `int**`, which  means a pointer to an int pointer.

If your compiler is generating an error when you *didn’t* use double asterisk in the function’s formal parameter list, thats because the type checking has failed. What you pass in to the function (ie the actual parameter) is `&ptr`, whose type is obviously `int**`.

C is a strongly typed language, so the C compiler forbids one to use an `int**` where `int*` is expected. But you can do `(int*)(ptr)` to cast ptr from one type to another.

On the other hand, If you’re using double asterisks in the function formal parameter list, but execute `printf(…, *p)`, it will print the address of the stack variable `ptr` from function main. It won’t print the value of a[0][0].

To wrap up, the double asterisk has two different semantics depending on the how you use it. When declaring a variable, `T **<variable name>` means a “second-order pointer to type T”. Yet at other times - when you’re not declaring variables but using them - “**” means dereferencing  twice.

Update: *what does double dereferencing mean?*

In c, every variable has an unique address. “Deference” is the operation of reading a value from an address that is indeterminate at compile time, and that address is in a value only known at run time. This value is called a pointer.

Double asterisk simply means to do the “dereference” operation first on a value, then do the “dereference” operation on the result.

Comment: I tried to use only one asterisk but its showing me error. WHY It does not work with that? If you send the address and then derefernce it then it supposed to work

Comment: Exactly, it should. But the problem is that you aren't sending the address of ```a[0][0]```, you're sending the address of ```ptr```, which is a different variable, has a different address than ```a[0][0]```.

Comment: As I said, it’s probably a type error. `int*` and `int**` are distinct types. And C is a strongly typed language, so the C compiler forbids one to pass in an `int**` where `int*` is expected.

Comment: To be clear, I seriously doubt "cast away the indirection" is the solution OP needs. While C will *allow* you to cast `int**` to `int*`, there are almost never good reasons to do that, and attempting to do anything nontrivial with the resulting `int*` will only cause problems.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It really helps. To sum up. ptr is already declared as a pointer, *ptr. Therefore, I need to dereference it using **ptr. like *(*ptr) right?

Comment: what does it mean by double dereferencing?

Comment: Fahi, the name of the pointer variable is ptr. Adding * in front of it already dereferences it. Note the duality of the semantics of * in C. Take a look at this tutorial: https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/introduction-to-pointers/ read the pointer part.

Answer (score 0):

A single `*` doesn't mean "a pointer to `char`", it means a pointer to whichever data type it is pointing at. In this case it's pointing to an `int`. Double asterisk means a pointer to pointer to `int`.

To dereference a pointer to an `int`, you'd use

```
int *p
```

But in this case, you passed a pointer to a pointer to an int. So to dereference the value, you'd need two levels of indirection. Hence

```
int **p
```

*Edit 1:* What is stored in the `ptr` variable is the address of `a[0][0]`, so a single level of indirection gives the address of `a[0][0]`, not the value stored at it.

*Edit 2:* The statement:

```
&ptr;
```

is sending the address of `ptr` variable to the function, which is a different from `a[0][0]` and has a different memory address.

Let's draw it out:

```
+------+       +-----------+
-      -       -           -     
- ptr  - ----> -  a[0][0]  - ---->  1
-      -       -           -
+------+.      +-----------+

A pointer to a pointer to an int.
```

Comment: Thanks for the last visualization. I am now confident with it. i saved all of the answer in my note

Comment: Anytime. Consider accepting the answer if it helped you.